# Can't input text in Bash function called with key binding

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, shell-script, bash-scripting, key-binding

I have added a simple function to my `.bashrc` file and bound it to a key combination using the `bind` command. The function prompts the user for input using `read`, like this:

```bash
myscript() {
    read -p "Enter input text: " input_text
    echo "$input_text"
}
```

I then bound this function to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> key combination using `bind` like this:

```bash
bind -x '"\C-g":myscript'
```

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, the function is called and the prompt `"Enter input text: "` is displayed, but I can't seem to type any input. The cursor just blinks and nothing happens.

I'm not sure what's causing this issue. How can I enable input in my Bash function that is called with a key binding?

#### Update:

Thanks to the answer by [Snell](https://superuser.com/a/1780245/1792260), I updated the function to be:

```bash
myscript() {
    echo -n "Enter input text: "
    read -e input_text
    echo "$input_text"
}
```

And now it works as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the issue you are experiencing might be related to the fact that you are running the function in the background as a shell command, rather than in the foreground as an interactive process.

You can try modifying your `myscript` function to run in the foreground by adding the `-i` option to the `read` command, like this:

```
myscript() {
    read -ei "Enter input text: " input_text
    echo "$input_text"
}
```

This will enable interactive editing for the `read` command, which should allow you to enter input when the function is called through the key binding.

Alternatively, you could modify the `bind` command to run the function in the foreground using the `-x` option, like this:

```
bind -x '"\C-g":myscript; bash -i'
```

The `bash -i` command at the end will start a new interactive shell session, which should allow you to enter input when the function is called through the key binding.

Comment: Thank you, adding the flag `-e` helped resolve the issue. I updated my question with the fixed function.

Comment: @Ramhound this answer is personally tested but not copied, hope so you understand it.

Comment: If you attest to the fact you wrote the code yourself, I will delete my comment, but stop copying external sources with quoting and citing your sources and/or using ChatGPT. It serves nobody. The content will be detected.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm pretty sure you have a good experience with GPT model but I would say that I don't use it maybe I can't express my truthfulness but I would say before posting anything I make it clear that the user understands it. As I'm new to this platform so I use highly elaborated texts after proper research and once I get older on this platform I might not write this long.

Comment: Consider the matter closed. No; My experience has proven that ChatGPT generates absolute trash content. I hate it more than plagiarized content. It will be detected. I and many others have a user script for that very purpose. There are obvious signs, which I won’t specifically point out, that are easy warning signs of AI generated content.